Error booting from newly installed SSD - Dependency failed for kernel-command-line.target
I have a problem with a new installed SSD on a raspberry pi 4, It is in some kind
boot loop. Looking at /var/log/boot.log  I see
------------ Thu Jul 04 01:17:10 BST 2024 ------------
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
rootfs: clean, 144709/7185024 files, 1603451/29173110 blocks
[  OK  ] Finished plymouth-read-write.service - Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
         Mounting proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount - Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
[  OK  ] Mounted proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount - Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-binfmt.service - Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service - Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization...
         Starting systemd-update-utmp.service - Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP...
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-update-utmp.service - Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP.
[  OK  ] Listening on systemd-rfkill.socket - Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
         Starting systemd-rfkill.service - Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
         Starting modprobe@dm_mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod...
         Starting modprobe@efi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi_pstore...
         Starting modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop...
[  OK  ] Finished modprobe@dm_mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod.
[  OK  ] Started systemd-rfkill.service - Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
[  OK  ] Finished modprobe@efi_pstore.service - Load Kernel Module efi_pstore.
[  OK  ] Finished modprobe@loop.service - Load Kernel Module loop.
         Starting modprobe@dm_mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod...
[  OK  ] Finished modprobe@dm_mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod.
[  OK  ] Started systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Reached target sysinit.target - System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Reached target time-set.target - System Time Set.
[  OK  ] Listening on dbus.socket - D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
         Starting alsa-restore.service - Save/Restore Sound Card State...
         Starting bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service...
         Starting kernel-command-line.service - Command from Kernel Command Line...
[FAILED] Failed to start kernel-command-line.service - Command from Kernel Command Line.
See 'systemctl status kernel-command-line.service' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for kernel-command-line.target - Command from Kernel Command Line.
[  OK  ] Removed slice system-modprobe.slice - Slice /system/modprobe.
[  OK  ] Stopped systemd-ask-password-plymouth.path - Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Stopped target time-set.target - System Time Set.
....

The system boots and runs fine from a SDcard with buster. I had built the new SSD
from the OS on the SDcard using
curl -O -J -O https://downloads.raspberrypi.com/raspios_arm64/ima\
   ges/raspios_arm64-2024-07-04/2024-07-04-raspios-bookworm-arm64.img.xz
sudo rpi-imager --cli --debug --first-run-script rpred.config \
   2024-07-04-raspios-bookworm-arm64.img.xz /dev/sda

My bootloader config, on the SD card, is "static" and the EEPROM is as follows
pi: sudo rpi-eeprom-update
BOOTLOADER: up to date
   CURRENT: Thu 11 May 06:26:03 UTC 2023 (1683786363)
    LATEST: Thu 11 May 06:26:03 UTC 2023 (1683786363)
   RELEASE: stable (/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/stable)
            Use raspi-config to change the release.

  VL805_FW: Dedicated VL805 EEPROM
     VL805: up to date
   CURRENT: 000138c0
    LATEST: 000138c0

pi: vcgencmd bootloader_version
2023/05/11 07:26:03
version 4fd8f1f3f7a05f7756edb1d3f15ffd7e428981f5 (release)
timestamp 1683786363
update-time 1728970004
capabilities 0x0000007f
pi: sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Anybody able to advise how I get this fixed.
PS> In response to a comment here is the rpred.config I attempted to use.
pi@raspberrypired:/mnt/SDcard/file/home/pi$ cat rpred.config
[pi]
hostname=raspberrypired
ssh_enable=true
pi@raspberrypired:/mnt/SDcard/file/home/pi$ 


Is there any clue in: systemctl status kernel-command-line.service?

Edit in the content of cmdline.txt on the boot partition of the SSD; if this includes init=rpred.config (I'm guessing that's what the imager might be doing, I've never used it and could not find documentation for the cli invocation), it's an invalid path.

Thanks goldilocks that put me on the right track. There was no "init=rpred.config" in my cmdline.txt however after lots of messing about. This involved downloading and trying various images going back years. All failed. I discovered that omitting the "--first-run-script" did the trick and allowed some, but not all images to load.
